# I have dell inspiron 545 desktop. It won't start up unless I remove the bios battery

Tags: boot, power, dell-inspiron, cmos

I have dell inspiron 545 desktop. It won't start up unless I remove the bios battery.

The issue first appeared  2 days ago. I left computer a few hours and when I got back the screen was black，lamp was blinking and Num Lock lamp on keyboard was on. Thought it went into sleep mode, but couldn't  wake it up. Pressed the Num Lock, the lamp won't turn off. So I pushed power button to shut it down.  Then a horrible thing happened it won't start up again!
I removed all plugs and opened it up. A green light on the back(power) and a amber light on the motherboard was always on. No bad caps was found.
when I pushed  power button , after reconnected the power, I noticed fans did try to start but couldn't . So I pushed longer time, then the computer began to start up for like 6-7 seconds, then shuts down again( power button was still pushed even after it shut down.)
After reset the BIOS and memory, by removing the CMOS battery and memory card, the computer was working again!

The next day the computer won't start up until I unplug everything and reset BIOS AGAIN! This time nothing happens no matter how long I push power button.

No problem was found when I  restart or start up some second after shut down.

Did run Dell Diagnostic and PSA，and I got :
Dell diagnostic:  fixed transformation and lighting test, cannot run
PSA: Error code:  0f00：133c
                              4400；011a

How can I fix this?  Can anyone help?

Comment: I'd start easy and hope it isnt hardware.  If you can get it up and running make sure you update anything driverwise tied to the bios.  Have you made any hardware changes?

Comment: Nope, didn't do anything unusual, only some windows update.

Comment: I went to Dell homepage tried to update drivers,but there were only one driver update related to my service tag and it was about removable storage . But there were 44 update related to my product, and one of them was about bios. The confusing thing is all  the updates was released years ago, since it worked fine before, really don't understand why is it causing problems now.

Comment: there are to many updates, do I need installer all of them? And the bios update couldn't be installed as instruction says. Under normal mode it says I don't have the right to access, under safe mode it says some thing like the driver couldn't be found.

Comment: Odds are drivers that old wont help with the problem.  how old is the machine?

Comment: about 4years。。。

Comment: I did some searching around the web on the error codes you posted...the most common cause was tied to hard-drives, though nothing I found mentioned having to reset the bios.  Try running chkdsk and see what that gives you.  I am kinda out of ideas...but maybe we can isolate the issue at least.

Answer (score -1):

I had these symptoms on my dell laptop.

I contacted support and they changed a tiny power transformer board and it was fine again.

For a PC I'd suggest you try an alternative power supply unit from your local hardware dealer.

Just make sure the power ratings match up to the stock power supply.